# file_get_contents returns an incorrect result if the content contains a sign "<" and a symbol after it

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I have a file that contains something like this:

```
first word<second word.
```

Next, I read the contents of this file using the function **file_get_contents**.
As a result, I do not get all the content, but only this part:

```
first word
```

I found out that the problem is the symbol "<" with the alphabet symbol after it. That is, in any case, when a similar sequence occurs in the content, the read result is obtained incorrectly and breaks down in this place.

I tried reading with other functions, like **fopen + fread**, but the result is the same.

Perhaps someone knows what might be the problem? Thankful in advance for any help in solving the problem.

Comment: You are outputting to a browser? If so convert the special characters (`<`, etc) to their entities so the browser doesn't think you have an element. http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php

Comment: exactly, browser doesn't display anything after <  considering it a HTML tag. Try looking at the page source. Right click -> view page source

Comment: @chris85 Really! For some reason I didn't think about the fact that the browser tries to process tags in this content. Thank you! The question is closed.